# Microsoft Teams and Azure DevOps integration versioning

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am investigating why I cannot set up a hook to integrate Teams and Azure DevOps. I am running two versions in different environments for comparison- but I am trying to hook the two together in the same environment.

First environment, version 1.3.00: This has the app built-in for Azure DevOps to hook and connect with Teams

Second environment, version 1.2.00: This version has no 'manage apps' button, and does not have anything referencing Azure DevOps or allowing to make any connection between Azure and Teams.  This is the environment I am trying to make the connection in.

Any thoughts on this? Does 1.2.00 version not offer the hook between Teams and Azure DevOps?  We do not have O365 accounts for this environment.

Answer (score 0):

To access the `Manage apps` page, you must be a global admin or Teams service admin. You may check your permission. Also, add microsoft-teams tag for you case may help you get more assistance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/manage-apps